# VBScript - Best way to confirm that the email has been received

Tags: vbscript

I sent an email to someone using this basic vbscript code and it works great but I want to confirm that the email has been received.
Is there a way to do this?
The code I use to send mail is:

```
Dim objMessage 'object mail

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
objMessage.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
objMessage.Subject = subjectStr
objMessage.From = "To someone"
objMessage.To = toWhoStr
objMessage.TextBody = contentStr 
objMessage.AddAttachment AttachmentFile

'==This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "ip smtp server"

'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1'cdoBasic


'Server port (typically 25)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587

'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = false

'Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection to the SMTP server)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

'==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

objMessage.Send

Set ObjMessage = Nothing
```

**UPDATE** I update my code and now I get notification to some e-mail.

```
Const CDO_SUCCESS = 4 ' sends delivery receipt if succesfull 
Const CDO_FAIL = 2 ' sends delivery receipt if fails 
Const CDO_DELAY = 8 ' sends delivery receipt if delayed 
Const CDO_SUCCESS_FAIL_DELAY = 14 ' sends delivery receipt always 

Dim objMessage 'object mail
Dim iConf
Dim Flds
    Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")  

    set iconf = createobject("cdo.configuration") 
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields 
    With Flds 
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "ip smtp server" 
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1'cdoBasic
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "username"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    .Update 
    End With 
    '==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

    With objMessage
        .BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
        Set .Configuration = iConf 
        .To = toWhoStr 
        .From = "from who" 
        .Subject = "BLA BLA BLA" 
        .TextBody = "PING PONG" 
        .fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:disposition-notification-to") = "email to notification" 
        .fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:return-receipt-to") = "email to notification"
        .DSNOptions = 14 
        .fields.update
        .Send
    End With 
    Set ObjMessage = Nothing
```

With this code when user that send to him the mail open the mail and try to close the mail then open popup that ask if he want to notification that he receipted the mail.

I not found a way that it's automatic send a notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the link below, that should point you in the right direction.

[Send CDO Mail with Read and Delivery Receipts](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1a7ba743-30e2-430e-99a4-9310396f99ef)

Lee.